# Hide records and their lookup children between subordinates

Tags: administration, security, profile, org-wide-defaults

I have a scenario where there is a Master Object-A and couple of child(lookup) objects-B,C,D,E related to the Master. I have some users in my system. I would like to set a security in such a way that A object and all its related child object can be viewed only by its owner and not any other user.

I know I can make all the objects as private and use manual sharing to give access to users who want to see that record, but in this case I do not know how many objects are related to A -> B,C,D...Z, which can also includes tasks,lookup object etc.

What I want is I will make all the object as private in Org wide setting and when I want to share a particular record and all its related objects,tasks with other users I should able to just share the parent object and all things related to that should be automatically shared.

Is this do able in Salesforce. Any suggestions?

Comment: (1) Does the OWD model have Grant Access Using Hierarchies unchecked? (2) did you look at apex managed sharing as a pathway to extend sharing on demand?

Comment: Grant access using hierarchies is checked, wondering why you asked that? I need to secure the records from roles which are on the same level. Example- Role Parent would have child 1, child 2 , child 3 roles. I need to secure the records on child level. I can not create a sharing rule in OWD for users belonging to each child because there are around 5000 children.

Comment: Can Apex Managed sharing solve this ?

Comment: 1) I asked about access via hierarchies as your OP wasn't clear whether you wanted parent Role user to not be able to see child Role user's objects. Per your comment, apparently that is NOT a requirement.  2) Apex Managed Sharing can work as it is the programmatic alternative to manually sharing the record and its children.  You'll need to use Apex Describe methods - `getChildRelationships()` to discover the children sobjects and then some clever coding to dynamically generate SOQL to find the objects to share

Comment: BTW - shouldn't the title of your OP be "Hide records and their lookup children `between` subordinates" ?

Comment: I agree that the title you suggested is more suitable. I read about apex manual sharing and seems like I can get the objects and its related objects using apex code. Assume I figure that out , I would have one more challenge.

Comment: Each child in subordinate has a group of user associated with it. I have to make the records of child only visible to users who are part of that child user group. How can I achieve that? Any idea? I thought to make a lookup field on User object so that I can associate the parent object with that user, but user object does not have an option to create a lookup field. I do not want to create a user group for each child subordinates because I might have to create 5000 or more user groups in that case. Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36808/discussion-between-crop1645-and-rdvsm).